# Creating tidy data frame showing co-occurrence: three columns for co-occurrence network using data from a list of uneven character vectors

Tags: r, matrix

I need help finding a solution to structure data for use with the r network package?

I have a list, author_list, containing several authors per character vector, e.g.:

document_authors1 = c("King, Stephen", "Martin, George", "Clancy, Tom")

document_authors2 = c("Clancy, Tom", "Patterson, James", "Stine, R.L.", "King, Stephen")

document_authors3 = c("Clancy, Tom", "Patterson, James", "Stine, R.L.", "King, Stephen")

author_list = list(document_authors1, document_authors2, document_authors3)

author_list

[[1]]
[1] "King, Stephen"  "Martin, George" "Clancy, Tom"

[[2]]
[1] "Clancy, Tom"      "Patterson, James" "Stine, R.L."      "King, Stephen"

[[3]]
[1] "Clancy, Tom"      "Patterson, James" "Stine, R.L."      "King, Stephen"

I need to create a data frame based on author_list within which there are three columns. The first two columns have the author names where col1 has a row value of one author and col2 has a row value of another author, and the third column, called, co-occurrence, provides the frequency by which the author pair (col1 and col2, row 1) occur. For example,

```
      col1                     col2                            co-occurrence
1 King, Stephen           Patterson, James                           2
2 Martin, George             Clancy, Tom                             1
```

Etc…

I have been trying to find a function from a package to do this but no luck. I've also been trying to piece together a solution step-by-step but this appears to be alluding me. Hopefully it's easier than I think. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to make your post more concise? Currently needs a lot of time to read(in my humble opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure this is what you are interested in, but hope this will be helpful.

```
library(dplyr)

# Only include elements in list with more than one author
author_list <- author_list[lengths(author_list)>1]

# Identify every combination of pairs of authors for each element in list
mat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(author_list), function(x) t(combn(author_list[[x]],2))))

# Within each row sort alphabetically 
mat <- t(apply(mat, 1, sort))

# Count up pairs of authors
as.data.frame(mat) %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
  summarise(count = n())

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   V1 [3]
  V1               V2               count
  <fct>            <fct>            <int>
1 Clancy, Tom      King, Stephen        3
2 Clancy, Tom      Martin, George       1
3 Clancy, Tom      Patterson, James     2
4 Clancy, Tom      Stine, R.L.          2
5 King, Stephen    Martin, George       1
6 King, Stephen    Patterson, James     2
7 King, Stephen    Stine, R.L.          2
8 Patterson, James Stine, R.L.          2
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need. One follow up question, please. I'm getting an error message: "Error in combn(author_list[[x]], 2) : n < m" when I run the solution with a list that includes a vector of only one author. Looking at the document for combn() it apears to be an issue with setting the value to "2". How can I set it to deal with single author vectors? I'm thinking I should maybe use list.filter to filter author_list to only those vectors with more than one author. Do you have any advice?

Comment: This  solved the issue of single vectors: 

author_list_author_remove = sapply(author_list, function(i) length(i) > 1)
author_list = author_list[author_list_author_remove]

Comment: Great - glad to hear. And another way to filter author_list to those with more than 1 author is: author_list[lengths(author_list)>1]